# Using a collection that already exists in Meteor

Tags: meteor

How do you access a Meteor collection that already exists? It's easy enough when you have created the collection in the session because you have a variable that references it, but you can't access a collection by name.

What happens if for example you want to retrieve documents from an existing collection in a new session where it is not being created for the first time. I have tried to 're-create' it hoping that it would just assign the existing collection to the new variable name (seeing that I can't find it by name), but it just throws an error to tell you that the collection already exists.

Comment: If the collection exists it should be accessible without any hassle. The name of the collection is given in `var collection = new Meteor.Collection("nameofcollection");`. Mongodb creates the collection if it doesn't exist, otherwise uses whats there. Could you give some code on what you're using to reference a collection?

Answer (score 0):

I've got some externally generated collections that I'm accessing via meteor. I'm not 100% sure that this will answer your question, but I hope it'll at least help.

One gotcha (doesn't apply to you it sounds like, here for completeness) is that if your collection was **not** created by Meteor, you'll need to export an environment variable to point Meteor to your DB.
For example, if the following env. variable is exported in the shell:

```
MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:3002/foo
```

...and then you invoke the meteor application, it'll point to the db "foo" in MongoDb, at which point you simply defined your collections as @Akshat mentions above in his comment:

```
collection = new Meteor.Collection("fooCollection") // this lives inside the foo DB.
```

If you're dealing with collections that have already been created by Meteor, by default they'll be inside the meteor db, eg:

```
MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:3002/meteor
```

...and you should be able to simply hook into them the same way; by simply declaring your collection and using it as you would. No need to create, obviously.

It sounds like you're already doing this but for other newcomers like me: in cases like this it's really handy to use the console in Chrome, Firefox, etc. and do some inserts that way - you'll see where your data lands, or you'll see other good bits of information that will help you home in on the issue - console.log() has saved my bacon a couple of times.

At any rate, it's worth validating exactly where the Meteor app is pointing vs. where you think it's pointing. Your collections should be accessible and should Just Work...